# Lowercase in loop doesn't work

Tags: python, list, for-loop, lowercase

This code works (in the scheme of my program)

```
name_list = []

for pmodel in Ndf["Purchase_1_Model"]:  
    name = pmodel.split(' ')[0]     
    name_list.append(name)

Ndf['Series_name'] = name_list
```

What I don't understand is why this does nothing additional

```
name_list = []

for pmodel in Ndf["Purchase_1_Model"]:  
    name = pmodel.lower
    name = pmodel.split(' ')[0]     
    name_list.append(name)

Ndf['Series_name'] = name_list
```

Can anyone offer me any guidance? Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing this is python? If so can you tag it as such.

Comment: add tag to the language you are using

Comment: You should tag with the actual language you are using, not just generic tags.

Comment: I've tagged it as python, but it's a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't use the `lower`'d version of `pmodel`.

You call `pmodel.lower` and assign this to variable `name`. You then do `split` on the *original*, *unmodified* `pmodel`, and assign this over the top of the existing value in `name`, replacing the version that was lowercase before.

You probably want to do something like the following:

```
for pmodel in Ndf["Purchase_1_Model"]:  
    lowered = pmodel.lower()
    name = lowered.split(' ')[0]     
    name_list.append(name)
```

Or simply:

```
for pmodel in Ndf["Purchase_1_Model"]:    
    name_list.append(pmodel.lower().split(' ')[0])
```

Comment: Also, if `pmodel` is a `String` as I'm assuming it is, you might need to call `pmodel.lower()`. Again I'm guessing on the language and the types...

Comment: I needed "()" at the end of "pmodel.lower"

Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: @user3489713 So was this python then? I'll re-tag the question appropriately if so...